# ImageMagick Errors: Convert PDF to Images

Tags: image, pdf, imagemagick

When I run the following command to convert a PDF to Image using ImageMagic Convert util with the following parameters :

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.5.8-Q16\convert.exe" "D:\RealDocs.pptx.pdf" "d:\hello.jpg"
```

I get the following error :

```
convert.exe: `%s': %s "gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dEPSCrop -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/Nupitch/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-xwOF7jbV" "-fC:/Users/Nupitch/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-BescEsek" "-fC:/Users/Nupitch/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-XfLll9WM" @ utility.c/SystemCommand/1964.convert.exe: Postscript delegate failed `D:\RealDocs.pptx.pdf': No such file ordirectory @ pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/634.convert.exe: missing an image filename `d:\hello.jpg' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2838.
```

please help me ~

Answer (score 21):

ImageMagick cannot handle PostScript and PDF files itself and by its own. For this it uses a third party software called *Ghostscript* as a 'delegate'.

Has your Windows system Ghostscript installed properly? Or is not installed at all?

Try to download and install the latest version from [**here**](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/).

Probably you'd get a different error message if the problem is caused by a missing Ghostscript installation. But your error is:

```
D:\RealDocs.pptx.pdf': No such file or directory 
@ pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/634.convert.exe: missing an image filename `d:\hello.jpg'
```

This could mean that the user account you run this command under does not have permission to write to the root of the `D:` drive.

To test this, you could run the conversion command in a cmd.exe window in a slightly modified way:

```
 "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.5.8-Q16\convert.exe" ^
      "D:\RealDocs.pptx.pdf" ^
      "%userprofile%\hello.jpg"
```

(On Windows XP, `%userprofile%` usually points to `c:\documents and settings\<your username>\`...)

Comment: Can you provide any PHP example `$obj = new Imagick();$readImg = $obj->readImage($src."[0]");`?

Comment: If you have issues downloading Ghostscript from their site. There is a mirror of some of the installers on SourceForge.