# How to covert PDF image to JPG or any in Magento

Tags: magento, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagick, php

Im developing and app in magento in the following way, the a downloadble product its uploaded, the i want to use imagick php and ghostcript to take the first page of pdf and put into the product thumbnail image.

I made a local integration with ghostscript and imagick php on local server using wamp 
with this code i cant convert the first page

exec("convert test.pdf[0] image.jpg ") ;  but when i introduce this code on magento i have the following error on apache

[Wed Dec 10 16:07:16.414295 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 6528:tid 900] [client 127.0.0.1:6737] AH01797: client denied by server configuration:magento/app/etc/local.xml
convert.exe: unable to open image `image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.exe: no images defined`image1112.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.

Could some one give a hand to resolve that

Thanks in advance !

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageMagick Errors: Convert PDF to Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591011/imagemagick-errors-convert-pdf-to-images) If it's not a duplicate of that, then there probably isn't enough information for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exec statement must be inside a function to work properly